# On constants attainable by the expression $\int_0^1xf(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, functions

> **Question.** Let $f:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ be an analytic, motonically increasing function such that $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. Let $K\in(0,1)$ be a constant such that $\int_0^1xf(x) \, dx=K$. For which $K$ does there exist such a function $f$, and for which $K$ is $f$ unique?

If we changed the expression $\int_0^1xf(x) \, dx$ to simply $\int_0^1f(x) \, dx$, is it easy to see that any $K\in(0,1)$ works and we certainly do not have any uniqueness. In the case $f(x)=x^\alpha$ for $\alpha\in\mathbb Z_{>0}$ we get $\int_0^1xf(x) \, dx=1/(\alpha+2)$, so at least rational numbers of this form are attainable. Intuitively, it feels like the condition $\int_0^1xf(x) \, dx=K$ is very weak, so there should for every attainable value of $K$ be many functions $f(x)$ attaining it, but I'm having lots of trouble showing this, or finding all attainable values for $K$. Any help is appreciated!

**P.S.** If it helps, this arose out of a physics problem where $f(x)$ models the height of a liquid at distance $x$ away from a reference point, and the condition $\int_0^1xf(x) \, dx=\text{constant}$ comes from volume conservation of the liquid. So the question of uniqueness of $f(x)$ answers whether or not the behaviour of the body of liquid is completely determined by the conditions listed above.

Comment: That analyticity condition is a bit of an obstacle. Just monotonicity and continuity wouldn't be a big deal.

Comment: Well for example your $x^{\alpha}$ example doesn't work if you require analyticity. I guess you could try something like $\frac{e^{cx}-1}{e^c-1}$  and see what you get.

Comment: If all you need is continuity then sure you can get anything in $(0,1/2)$ and there is absolutely no uniqueness in that range. You also can't get out of there since $\int_0^1 x f(x) dx$ will be strictly between $\int_0^1 0 dx=0$ and $\int_0^1 x dx = 1/2$.

Comment: @Ian I have changed the conditions back to analyticity after thinking about it again, and it seems that this is the right assumption. Sorry for the confusion, cheers!

Comment: Analycity makes no difference what-so-ever. You can get any $K \in (0,1/2)$ with multiple analytic strictly increasing $f$. In fact, it would still be true if you restricted $f$ to be polynomial of degree $\le 3$

Comment: @PaulSinclair Interesting, if you could write that up as an answer (with proof, of course) I'd gladly accept it.

Comment: It may take higher degrees than 3 to cover everything (a quadratic function will only give $K \in (1/4, 1/3)$). The hard part is making sure that the polynomial is increasing on $[0,1]$ while still allowing freedom. My ability to work on it is limited, so it may be tomorrow evening before I can actually work it out (I can do degree 2 in my head, but not 3).

Comment: @Paul: yes, indeed ensuring motonicity was the main trouble I had too. Appreciate the effort!

Comment: Since you can get $1/(n+2)$, you can use convex combinations of the $x^n$ to get any number between $1/(n+2)$ and $1/(n+2+i)$ for integer $i \ge 1$. This gives you every $K$ in $(0,1/3],$ and these values are non-uniquely attained. Dunno about $>1/3$.

Comment: Since monotonicity persits under convex combinations, I think the question boils down to what $\sup \int x f(x)$ is under the conditions stated. Then by the same trick as the previous comment every value under it should be attainable non-uniquely. It *is* more than $1/3,$ the function $\frac{ 1-e^{-x}}{1-e^{-1}}$ gets $>0.37$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that if $f$ and $g$ satisfy the given conditions, then so does any convex combination of $f$ and $g$. Thus the set of attainable values is a convex subset of the reals, i.e. an interval.

This means that if $S = \sup \int xf(x)$ and $I = \inf \int x f(x)$ both subject to the given conditions, then any value in $(I,S)$ can be attained.

Further, the infimum $I$ is clearly $0$, and a sequence approaching this infimum is $P_n := x^n$ for integer $n$. This also means that any value in $(I,S)$ can be attained non-uniquely as a convex combination of some function that gets a value close to $S$ and the various $x^n$ for sufficiently large $n$.

The question remains what $S$ is, and if it can be attained. I'll argue that $S = 1/2,$ and it cannot be attained. The latter claim is easy if $S = 1/2$: since $f$ is analytic, thus continous, and it is $0$ close to $0$, then $xf(x) < x/2$ for $x < \varepsilon$ for some small $\varepsilon > 0,$ giving $\int xf < \varepsilon/4 + (1-\varepsilon)/2 < 1/2.$

Next, we argue that $S = 1/2$. Note that $S \le 1/2$ trivially, since $f \le 1.$

@Dark Malthorp below points out a simple witness for $S \ge 1/2:$ consider $f_n := 1 - (1-x)^n.$ This is easily seen to satisfy the conditions required. Further, $$ \int x f_n(x) = \frac{1}{2} - \int_0^1 x(1-x)^n \ge \frac{1}{2} - \int_0^1 (1-x)^n = \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{n+1}. $$

Comment: Getting up to $S=1/2$ is easy because any continuous function can be uniformly approximated with polynomials.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp Of course! That's simple enough, let me put that in.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp actually, wait, no - trivially there are continuous non-decreasing functions that approach $1/2,$ but how do I know that the polynomial approximations are non-decreasing on $[0,1]$?

Comment: Yea that is a difficulty. It should be possible but a proof is not obvious

Comment: @DarkMalthorp I was thinking $\int_0^x e^{-t^n} dt$ appropritately normalised. Then the $f_n$ are cumulative distributions weakly approching the point mass at $0$, and the value is $(1-\mathbb{E}[X^2])/2$ for $X$ with cdf $f_n$. Let me see if there's a  catch somewhere...

Comment: Wait actually we've been over thinking this: $1- (1 - x)^n$.

Comment: @DarkMalthorp Lol, you're right. More editing :)

Comment: Thank you both for the elegant solution, and for teaching me about convex combinations which I did not know of prior to this.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: Turns out I made a careless mistake in my answer and didn't manage to prove the case of infinite solutions for $K\in(0,1/2)$, only $K\in(0,1/3)$. I'll leave my answer here for now, but feel free to reference or extend it to give a more complete solution.

<strike>There will be infinitely many $f$ for $K\in(0,1/2)$, while outside that range no such $f$ exists since $0=\int_0^10dx<\int_0^1 xf(x)dx<\int_0^1xdx=1/2$ (as pointed out by Ian in the comments)</strike>

To show the first statement, you can construct infinite families of solutions in many ways. Here's one that I got: given a $K\in(0,1/3)$, we can show that for all $n>1/K>3$, the infinite family of functions $f_n(x)=(1-a_n)x+a_nx^{n-2}$, where $a_n=\frac{1/3-K}{1/3-1/n}$, all satisfy the given conditions.

Clearly, $f_n(0)=0,f_n(1)=1$. If we perform the integral, we get
$$
\int_0^1(1-a_n)x^2+a_nx^{n-1}dx
=\frac13(1-a_n)+\frac{a_n}{n}=\frac{1}3\frac{K-1/n}{1/3-1/n}+\frac{1}n\frac{1/3-K}{1/3-1/n}\\=\frac{1}{1/3-1/n}\left(\frac13K-\frac1{3n}+\frac1{3n}-\frac1nK\right)=K
$$
and finally, using the inequalities $\frac13>K>\frac1n$, we have
$$
0\le a_n=\frac{1/3-K}{1/3-1/n}\le1
$$
and therefore for all $x\in[0,1]$
$$
f'_n(x)=(1-a_n)+a_n(n-2)x^{n-3}\ge0
$$
which implies $f_n$ is monotonically increasing over this interval.

Comment: Trouble - $\int x^2 = 1/3,$ not $1/2$, which scuppers the solution a bit because then the value is $ 1/3 - a_n(1/3 - 1/n),$ and I'm not sure you can make $a_n$ negative enough to get values (much) bigger than $1/3$ while still retaining monotonicity...

Comment: Ah, you're right. Looks like I only proved it for $k\in(0,1/3)$ then. I'll leave my answer at $k\in(0,1/3)$ for now, and I'll try to prove $k\in(0,1/2)$ when I have time tomorrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(x)=\exp\big(\frac{\alpha}{\log(1-x)}\big),$ $x\ne0,1.$

$$ \int_0^1xf(x)~dx=K$$ where $K=2K_1(2)-\sqrt{2}K_1(2\sqrt{2})$ for $\alpha=1.$ Here $K_1$ is the modified Bessel function of the second kind.

$$\lim_{\alpha\to0}\int_0^1xf(x)~dx=1/2.$$

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delay - I had some unexpected issues to deal with when I got home.

My claim that it would be possible to get all $K \in (0,1/2)$ using only cubic polynomials turns out not to be true. The largest $K$ obtainable with cubics is $9/20$ for $f(x) = x^3 - 3x^2 + 3x$. While the minimum appears to be $\approx 0.162$ for $f(x) = x^3 +bx^2 + cx$ where $b = (\sqrt{76} - 16)/10$ and $c = b^2/3$ (though I haven't confirmed that it is definitely the lowest).

Letting $$f(x) = \dfrac {x^3 + bx^2 + cx}{1 + b + c}$$
gives integrals 
$$\int_0^1 xf(x)\,dx = \frac 1{1+b+c}\left(\frac 15 + \frac b4 + \frac c3\right) = \frac {12+15b + 20c}{60(1 + b + c)}$$

Setting $$ \frac {12+15b + 20c}{60(1 + b + c)} = K$$ gives curves in $(b,c)$ coordinates all corresponding to the same $K$, so there is no uniqueness here. The function $f$ will be increasing on $[0,1]$ for the shaded regions of $(b,c)$ space:

[image]

To find larger or smaller $K$, you need higher degree polynomials: $f(x) = x^n$ gives an integral of $1/(n+2)$, while $f(x) = 1 - (x-1)^{2n}$ gives an integral of $1/2 - 1/(2n+1)(2n+2)$